# OPTIONS Resource failed to load - Basic authentication + SSL - Chrome / Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, ssl, safari, basic-authentication

I currently encounter an issue with Chrome and Safari but not with Firefox.
I'm just trying to send a basic `GET` request to the server. This one use SSL and the basic authentication with `"username:password"` encoded in base64. Below, an example :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://(...)',
  type: "GET",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    var base64 = 'dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=';
    return xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
  }
});
```

The Chrome developer tool shows me an error :

```
OPTIONS https://(...) Resource failed to load 
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send
f.extend.ajax
```

[image]

What could I do ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks to me like XSS protection. Even though the error looks odd.

To overcome that you would have to use jsonp. However that would mean you have to put the user/pass into the url plaintext, so it's not a real solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    var auth; 

function make_base_auth(user, password) {
    var tok = user + ':' + password;
    var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;
}

function getAuthCookie() {

    var cn = "Authorization=";
    var idx = document.cookie.indexOf(cn)
    var end;

    if(idx != -1) {
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", idx + 1);
        if(end == -1)
            end = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(idx + cn.length, end));
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

       document.cookie = encodeURIComponent("Authorization") + "=deleted; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString(); 
       auth = make_base_auth($.trim($('#email').val()), $.trim($('#password').val()));
   document.cookie = "Authorization=" + auth;


             $.ajax({
        url : BASE_URI + "user",
        method : "GET",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', getAuthCookie());
        },
        xhrFields : {
            withCredentials : true
        },
        accept : "application/json",
        contentType : "application/json",
        cache : false,
        cookie : false,
        statusCode : {
            404 : function() {
                console.log("Page Not Found");
            } 
        }

    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log("Login SUCCESS " + JSON.stringify(response));

           }).fail(function(response) {

    }).then(function() {

           });
```